# Should I use repeated measures anova? and what post hoc should I use?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have an independent variable which is observed 3 times over the span of 78 hours (24, 48, 72) respectively. Should I use repeated measure anova or should I treat the hours of observation as a dependent variable and peform two way anova?

The treatments has only been applied once and a total of 2 replicatea and trials were performed

Comment: Please can you clarify the structure of your experiment - do you have two groups you are comparing: i.e. a control/untreated group and a treated group, with two replicates in each group, and for each replicate you have measured the response variable at 3 time points?

Comment: Thabk you for the reponse. Yes precisely I have 2 control groups the negative and positive and 3 experimental groups that have 2 replicates with 2 trials.

Comment: Does thay mean by getting the mean of each treatment I can suffice the assumptions for a repeated measures anova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, my understanding of your experimental structure is as follows:

- 2 trials
- Each trial consisted of the same 5 treatments (negative and positive control, plus 3 experimental treatments), with two replicates of each treatment in each trial.
- In each trial and for each treatment, the response variable was measured on three separate occasions, at equal time intervals of 24 hours.

NB. You refer to observing the 'independent variable'. I would call the response variable, that you expect to be influenced by the treatments, the 'dependent variable', because you think its value is dependent on whatever treatments you've used. Your independent variables in this case are treatment (a categorical variable/factor with 5 levels), time and trial). Describing time in this case as a dependent variable would not make sense - the passage of time isn't dependent on anything that you have done! Time would only be a dependent variable if it was measured as the response variable - e.g. if we measured how long it took people of different heights to run 100m, height would be the independent variable, and time (taken to run 100m) would be the dependent/response variable.

Considering one trial at a time to start with - yes, from your description, it appears to me that you can indeed use a repeated measures ANOVA, with time point and treatment as independent variables. But you shouldn't take the mean of each treatment before carrying out the ANOVA as you suggest in a comment above: you need to include each replicate, because ANOVA uses information not only on the mean but also on the variance of each group.

Considering both trials together is more tricky, because now your treatments are nested within 'Trial'. The factor 'Trial' could also affect your response variable. It could even affect the variance of your response variable, which would violate one of the assumptions of ANOVA (but there are alternative analyses to deal with that, such as REML). It's difficult to comment on how to treat your 'Trial' factor, because you haven't explained the difference between your two trials and how it might affect your response variable - e.g. were they carried out in a different month? or at a different site? I am assuming that they both had the same treatment structure. Without more specific information I don't think it's a good idea for me to give any strong opinions on how to deal with this.

One alternative to repeated measures ANOVA that is available to you is to use a mixed model, to deal with your nesting within trial, and your levels of treatment and time. Then you could treat time as a continuous or ordinal variable, if you wanted to.

Some cautionary notes:

- With only two replicates per treatment, your power to detect any difference that exists is going to be quite low. So you are unlikely to get any significant results with this experimental structure, even if actually there are differences. A failure to detect a difference that actually exists is called a 'Type II error'.
- Your comments re: describing your response variable as an 'independent variable' and using the treatment mean indicate to me that you might find it helpful to read up on different types of variable and the meaning of 'dependent' and 'independent', and also on using ANOVA. You may also find it helpful to try out some practical examples to get more familiar with the concepts of 'basic' ANOVA before you attempt a repeated measures ANOVA.